# Returning value of the predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and I need help understanding how returning value works.
I know that it's either

```
pred(Y, X) :- X is Y.
```

So when giving input

```
?- pred(5, X).
```

output is:
`X = 5.`

or when input is

```
?- pred(5,5).
```

we get:
`true .`

Now I would like to obtain the first output from the predicate that looks like this:

```
main_pred(List, RES) :-
sort(List, SortedList),
check(SortedList).
```

The RES should be either `T` if `check(SortedList)` is true or `N` if `check(SortedList)` is false.
For now my result is just true/false, but I would like to get `RES = T/N`.

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When check succeeds, return RES the second argument equal to true

```
main_pred(List, true) :-
    sort(List, SortedList),
    check(SortedList), !.    
main_pred(List, false).
```

Otherwise return RES=false. More directly:

```
main_pred(List, RES) :-
    sort(List, SortedList),
    (check(SortedList) -> RES=true; RES=false).
```

Replace true/false by the values you want (T/N). Does this reply your question?

Answer (score 1):

**1-** `main_pred` predicate takes a list `([1,2,3])`, checks if it's ordered.

**2-** If it is ordered, returns `RES=true`, else `RES=false`.

**Note:** I have commented sort, because if we use it, then it will always return `RES=true`.

```
main_pred(List, RES) :-
%sort(List, SortedList),
(ordered(List)->
    RES='true';
    RES='false').

ordered([]) .
ordered([_]) .
ordered([X,Y|Z]) :- X =< Y , ordered( [Y|Z] ),!.
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
?-main_pred([1,3,5],Res).
Res = true

?-main_pred([1,4,2],Res).
Res = false
```